# vRealize REST API and snapshots

Tags: api, rest, vmware

Is there any way to work with snapshots via VMWare vRealize REST API?

I look through http://pubs.vmware.com/vra-62/index.jsp#com.vmware.vra.programming.doc/GUID-EB4D5D6C-20A5-4189-AE75-97F86D53677F.html and can't figure it out, but there is a constant feeling that the doc is rather poor and there are more things hidden...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Short answer is yes, a list of action for the VM can be requested through the catalog-service API (Ex. /api/consumer/resources/{resourceId}/actions).

The resourceId is the UUID of the VM.  Each VM action maybe different so in my scripting I query for available actions each time to verify the requested action is available.  Once you have the UUID of the VM and the UUID of the action then you may request the JSON payload from the action template and manipulate to meet your needs, again I do this all through scripting (python).

Once the payload is ready just push up to the API to make the call (Ex. /api/consumer/resources/{resourceId}/actions/{resourceActionId}/requests).  If you would like more details on how to format the json please let me know.